# Unknown 10-pin connector used in a slip ring

Tags: identification, connector, slip-ring

I was looking to buy a slip ring for lidar module that I making by myself. I found this one (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000346538510.html).
However even the seller doesn't know the connector used in this slip ring. So does anybody know what this connector's type is?

Here are some pictures of it:

[image: Connector]

[image: Connector 2]

[image: Connector 3]

The dimensions are 3mm * 8 mm

Comment: To make it possible to identify connectors, please post some more information: Pitch of the pins, number of pins - this looks like a double sided. It also helps to have a picture of the other side. Measurements of outside. It can also help to get some information of context (what kind of equipment).

Comment: Also the resolution is bad and a picture of the actual contacts would be helpful. Doesn't look like crimp(?) but some custom one(?).

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I've updated the post with more informations.

Comment: What’s the center to center distance between the pins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to tell from the photo, but I suspect this may be an 'edge connector' that is designed to mate with gold-plated fingers on the edge of a PCB, in a similar way to ISA or PCI bus connectors.

If so, you need to measure the pin pitch, then try to find a sacrificial PCB with the correct thickness, and contact spacing.

Alternatively, just chop the connectors off, and solder on something more convenient.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I will just chop the connector and solder the cables on an XH2 connector.